# When does reactor execute a subscription chain?

Tags: project-reactor

The reactor [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_from_imperative_to_reactive_programming) states the following:

> Nothing happens until you subscribe

If that was true, why do I see a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I run the following code snippet, which has a reactor chain without a subscription?

```
    @Test
    void test() {
        String a = null;
        Flux.just(a.toLowerCase())
                .doOnNext(System.out::println);
    }
```

Comment: You get a `NullPointerException` because you're calling `a.toLowerCase()` where `a` is `null`. It has nothing at all to do with reactor, just plain and simple Java. Note that `a.toLowerCase()` is evaluated because you're passing the result of that expression to a method (in this case the method `Flux.just(...)` but it could have been any other method).

Answer (score 3):

Deepak,

*Nothing happens* means the data will not be flowing through the chain of your functions to your consumers until a subscription happens.

You're getting `NPE` because Java tries to compute the value which is given to a **hot operator** `just()` on the Flux definition step.

You can also convert `just()` to a **cold operator** using `defer()` so you will receive `NPE` only after a subscription happened:

```
public Flux<String> test() {
    String a = null;
    return Flux.defer(() -> Flux.just(a.toLowerCase()))
            .doOnNext(System.out::println);
}
```

Please, read more about [hot vs hold](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#reactor.hotCold) operators.

### Update:

Small example of cold and hot publishers. Each time new subscription happens cold publisher's body is recalculated. Meanwhile, `just()` is only producing time that was calculated only once at definition time.

```
Mono<Date> currentTime = Mono.just(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Mono<Date> realCurrentTime = Mono.defer(() -> Mono.just(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));

// 1 sec sleep
Thread.sleep(1000);
currentTime.subscribe(time -> System.out.println("Current Time " + time.getTime()));
realCurrentTime.subscribe(time -> System.out.println("Real current Time " + time.getTime()));

Thread.sleep(2000);
currentTime.subscribe(time -> System.out.println("Current Time " + time.getTime()));
realCurrentTime.subscribe(time -> System.out.println("Real current Time " + time.getTime()));
```

The output is:

> Current Time **1583788755759**
>
> Real current Time **1583788756826**
>
> Current Time **1583788755759**
>
> Real current Time **1583788758833**

Comment: Thank you. I have two follow up questions:
1. "because Java tries to compile the value", I thought NPEs were RuntimeExceptions so I don't understand how it is possible to catch them during compilation.
2. What happens when a hot publisher is part of a cold publisher chain? Is it still evaluated before it is subscribed to?

Comment: @DeepakBhimaraju, 1. Sorry, I expressed this wrong. You're absolutely right and the error will appear only on execution time. I've updated my answer. 2. No, in this case cold publisher's body will be executed each time new subscription happens and all the expressions defined inside will be recalculated.

Comment: https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription